# Can I see which stored procedures are used in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any way to see the tables and stored procedures used in SSRS Report.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There not an easy way that I know of. As far as I know, you would need to check the Dataset of the report and check the query tab for the SQL query of the stored procedure.

[image]

If you want to check the code, the query is in the **XML < CommandText>** tag.

Answer (score 0):

**This if you don't have access to the project:**

If the report is deployed, go to Report Manager Site download the RDL file of the report and open it in visual studio. Open datasets and you can visualize the actual queries.